# Formula to count each individual digit in a cell per column in Excel

Tags: excel, numbers, digits

I have a list of numbers like below. And I need to know how many of each number are in each cell per column.

```
My List
1
2
3
4
10
11
12
13
14
21
22
23
24
```

I need to know how many times 1 occurs throughout the whole list, including double digit numbers, and I need to do this for each number 0-9. The reason I don't just count them is because I have a total of 1,400 numbers that I need to break down. I have tried =COUNTIF but unfortunately it sees numbers such as 22 and ONE number, when I need it to tell me that there are 2, 2s. Is there a way? Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look at this? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214153

Answer (score 0):

With your data in `A2:A15` and the digit to count in `B2` you can use following array formula (confirmed with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`):

```
=SUM(LEN(A2:A15)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A15,B2,"")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a way of doing it:-

```
=SUM(LEN(A$1:A$10)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A$1:A$10,"1","")))
```

and the same for "2", "3" etc. or put digits 0-9 in a range of cells starting at  (say) B1 and enter this in C1 and pull down:-

```
=SUM(LEN(A$1:A$10)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A$1:A$10,B1,"")))
```

Is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

To count **1**'s, use something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A2:A14)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A14,"1","")))
```

[image]

You can count any digit or character or substring this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only ever considering up to double-digit numbers, as you appear to suggest:

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(MID(A$1:A$10,{1,2},1)="1"))`

Or, more dynamically, with e.g. 1 in B1:

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(MID(A$1:A$10,{1,2},1)=""&B1))`

and copied down.

Regards